# How to see why bundle requirements are not fulfilled in Apache Felix Log?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix, gogo-shell

I'm using Felix in embedded mode, with the File Install bundle, and have a bundle that is Installed but not Resolved (thus not Starting / Active), and I'm struggling more than I thought one would have to finding the root cause in the log...

How / where do you get those helpful looking "Unable to resolve ... because..." or "BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle ... Unable to resolve ... missing requirement ... osgi.wiring.package" kind of messages in the log, automatically from Felix framework and/or the File Install bundle? I'm not seeing anything like that - should I be? Where?

I've also added logging (via [Apache Felix Log](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-log.html) and [osgi-loglistener-slf4j](https://github.com/everit-org/osgi-loglistener-slf4j)), but still nada - do you need to do more than I did for enabling logging for this kind of problem in (Embedded) Felix?

I've then added the Felix Gogo Shell CLI, and found that its `inspect` command, isn't very helpful either (does not work for bundles that are not resolved), and only `start` will show the root cause - but how can I get this to get logged, without having to have a console and do a start:

```
g! lb  
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (5.6.1)|5.6.1
    1|Active     |    1|Apache Felix File Install (3.5.4)|3.5.4
    2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Remote Shell (1.1.2)|1.1.2
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.16.2)|0.16.2
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.16.0)|0.16.0
    5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.12.0)|0.12.0
    6|Installed  |    1|osgi.testplugin (1.0.0.SNAPSHOT)|1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
g! inspect req * 6
Bundle 6 is not resolved.
g! start 6
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve ch.vorburger.minecraft.osgi.testplugin [8](R 8.0): missing requirement [ch.vorburger.minecraft.osgi.testplugin [8](R 8.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.spongepowered.api.command) Unresolved requirements: [[ch.vorburger.minecraft.osgi.testplugin [8](R 8.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.spongepowered.api.command)]
```

I do understand that due to OSGi's async bundle initialization, it may not be obvious when to log a failed bundle start, as it may have to wait for dependent bundles to come up? Couldn't it still.. log this kind of error, after some sort of grace period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in tests before I found the pax exam option to check that all bundles are resolved.

What I did was to programmatically go through the list of bundles and call start on each bundle that is not started. bundle.start() then throws an exception with the reason like the console command above.

Not sure if felix can be set to also log this by default.

Comment: Right.. so is the problem here then really is not Felix Framework core, but that the the File Install bundle "swallows" the exception from the bundle.start() its doing on start or when it notices changes in the directory it watches? Is that a fair bug report, and perhaps a contribution with a LOG error() or warn() there would be sensible? Or is it perhaps intentionally swallowed - are there scenarios imaginable when File Install should ignore bundle start errors without logging (perhaps because it will retry, and so 'polluting' the log would not be desirable)?

Comment: It is definitely worth opening an issue at felix. Maybe fileinstall can be configured to show the error, but it also might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is best solution, but it helped me

```
import org.osgi.framework.*;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator, BundleListener {

    public void start(BundleContext context) {
        context.addBundleListener(this);
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) {
        context.removeBundleListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void bundleChanged(BundleEvent bundleEvent) {
        if (bundleEvent.getType() == BundleEvent.UNRESOLVED) {
            System.out.println("BUNDLE " + bundleEvent.getOrigin().getSymbolicName() + " UNRESOLVED");
        try{
            System.out.println("TRYING TO START " + bundleEvent.getOrigin().getSymbolicName() + " BUNDLE");
            bundleEvent.getOrigin().start();

        } catch (BundleException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

and add activator config to .bnd file

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .
Bundle-Activator: com.netcracker.webportal.framework.activator.Activator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework
```